# Using set_column vertically to describe the index of the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization

I have a pivot-like table below where I am trying to set a caption for the data. I reconfigured the format of the `pivot_table` code so that it doesn't create this awkward looking multiindex format. Instead I just want captions to describe the columns and the index.

Below is an example dataframe. Below I only know the code for the column headers which is "Letters". What I want is an index header (running vertically and not horizontally as well) for "Numbers". Below would be an attempt, which doesn't work.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(15, 12)), columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJKL'))
df.style.set_caption('Letters')
df.index.style.set_caption('Numbers')
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading through the documentation I don't know if it's possible to assign an index header with pd style. Here's a hack which makes a heatmap to show your table and you can customize the axes labels (requires seaborn and matplotlib...)

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(15, 12)), columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJKL'))

ax = sns.heatmap(
    df,
    annot=True,
    cbar=False,
    #cmap=matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(['white']), #uncomment to all white color
)
ax.set_yticks([])
ax.xaxis.tick_top()
ax.xaxis.set_label_position('top')
ax.set_xlabel('X-label name')
ax.set_ylabel('Y-label name')
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

[image]